# python - convert datetime to UTC time

Tags: python

I would like to convert `datetime` to `UTC` time. I try below code but the output looks like not correct:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def str2dt(tstr):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tstr, '%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    return dt

ts = "04-12 20:43:34.342"
dt = str2dt(ts)

utc_delta = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.now()
utc = dt - utc_delta
print(dt,'->',utc)
```

Current output:
1`900-04-12 20:43:34.342000 -> 1900-04-12 15:43:34.342001`

The expected output time is `1900-04-12 02:43:34.342001`

Comment: what's `utc_delta`?

Comment: I think the use of the `pytz` for timezone is what you need to convert between local vs UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you would be better off using `isoformat()` on your `datetime`:

```py
utc = dt.isoformat(sep=' ')  # The normal date-time separator is 'T', but that isn't very readable
print(f"{dt} -> {utc}")
```

This gives you the answer you're looking for.

If you still need the UTC offset, consider using `datetime.datetime.utcoffset()`.

Comment: Not sure why it output the same time: 2022-04-12 20:43:34.342000 -> 2022-04-12 20:43:34.342000

Comment: Make sure that the timezone is being initialized accurately. Python might believe that the time is already at UTC+0.

Answer (score 1):

Should be plus the delta:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def str2dt(tstr):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tstr, '%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    return dt

ts = "04-12 20:43:34.342"
dt = str2dt(ts)

utc_delta = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.now()
utc = dt + utc_delta
print(dt,'->',utc)
```

Output:

```
1900-04-12 20:43:34.342000 -> 1900-04-13 01:43:34.341999
```